# How to format a complicated formula that includes exponents in Java

Tags: java, formulas, exponent, temperature

Update: Ok, it all works now. I figured out what I was doing wrong. In the formula, rH (relative humidity) is supposed to be in a percentage, i.e. "30%". The required input format for the assignment is percent as a decimal, i.e. ".30". Such a simple fix and I didn't even see it. I kept inputting the .30 without converting it to the whole percentage. So I fixed that with a simple .30 * 100 and there it was. Thank you all for helping me, I don't know if I can do the check mark for all the answers so I just picked one.

I am trying to write a code to calculate the dew point. My code works, but the formula I was using was too simple and I wasn't able to get an accurate answer. I found a more advanced formula, which is quite lengthy, and it includes a few exponents. I have been trying to find out how to properly format it, and so far the only thing I've been able to find is the math.pow method, which I think is too simple for this problem. I could be wrong, of course, since I have only been using java for about two weeks.

The formula in question is:

Tdc = (Tc - (14.55 + 0.114 * Tc) * (1 - (0.01 * RH)) - ((2.5 + 0.007 * Tc) * (1 - (0.01 * RH))) ^ 3 - (15.9 + 0.117 * Tc) * (1 - (0.01 * RH)) ^ 14)

The two exponents are the ^3 and ^4. How would I write that in java? As I said, the program does work, this is a simple issue with formatting the formula. Thanks.

EDIT: The website where I found this formula is http://www.angelfire.com/ok5/orpheus/metcal.html

It is in about the middle of the page. It does show ^14, and not 4. I didn't catch that at first, I will double check to see which one works.

Comment: I think you already answered your own question. Math.pow(double, double) is the method for raising a value to an exponent.

Comment: You mean `^4`, not `^14`, right?

Comment: I was about to ask how you would format, but someone showed it below. Thank you for answering. I just didn't think I could put an equation in there, I thought it had to be a single number. Like I said, I'm very new to this so I don't yet know how much I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

14 as exponent is highly unusual but seems to be correct according to "Linsley et al. (1989)"

If you are working with local variables, you should use lowercase names.

Finally, you could define a temp variable equal to `1 - 0.01 * rh` since you use it three times in a row :

```
double tc = 23; // just an example
double rh = 67; // just an example
double rh2 = 1 - (0.01 * rh);
double tdc = tc - (14.55 + 0.114 * tc) * rh2 -
        Math.pow((2.5 + 0.007 * tc) * rh2, 3) -
        (15.9 + 0.117 * tc) * Math.pow(rh2, 14);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try. Unable to work on it now as the code is on another computer.

Comment: The site I got the formula from does actually show 14, not 4. I will double check on that.

Comment: That'd be the first time I see any formula with 14 as exponent, but who knows? Do you have a reference?

Comment: I put the website link in the original post above. But here it is, I still had it on the clipboard http://www.angelfire.com/ok5/orpheus/metcal.html

Comment: So far, your version has had the most success. I'm still not able to replicate the example I was given but it's a lot closer. I'm going to keep working on this. It could be messing up somewhere else now. I'll post the full code if I need to, but it's a homework assignment and I want to do as much as I can on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Exponents are done with the `Math` library. Speciefically `Math.pow(a, b)`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-

Further, I would split the constituent parts of your equation into smaller variables that make sense. Then combine the parts into your final equation.

Ex: `double termTc1 = 14.55 + (0.114 * Tc); // Do not use this name, give them meaningful names`

Comment: I'll see how this works when I get a chance, the code is on another computer.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you suggested, use the `Math.pow` function:

```
    double tdc = Tc -
            (14.55 + 0.114 * Tc) * (1 - (0.01 * RH)) -
            Math.pow(((2.5 + 0.007 * Tc) * (1 - (0.01 * RH))), 3) -
            (15.9 + 0.117 * Tc) * Math.pow((1 - (0.01 * RH)), 14);
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I wasn't sure if I could put an entire equation in there like that, I thought it would only work with a single integer or double. Thank you.

Comment: glad I could help.

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: I'll try to see if this works a little later, as the code is on another computer and I am unable to work on it.

Comment: Wasn't me down-voting earlier, but I'm now down-voting because *that* is not the same formula. Exponent has highest precedence, so you have way too much inside the `pow()` calls, e.g. see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42032017/5221149).

Answer (score 1):

I would format like this:

```
double tdc = tc - (14.55 + 0.114 * tc) * (1 - (0.01 * rh))
                - Math.pow((2.5 + 0.007 * tc) * (1 - (0.01 * rh)), 3)
                - (15.9 + 0.117 * tc) * Math.pow(1 - (0.01 * rh), 14);
```

It does however show two potential errors in your formula:

- Should the second exponent really be 14, not 4?
- Should the multiplier expression for the second exponent really be *outside* the exponent?

Perhaps *(?)* the correct formula is this, with alignment to show the pattern of the formula:

```
double tdc = tc -          (14.55 + 0.114 * tc) * (1 - (0.01 * rh))
                - Math.pow(( 2.5  + 0.007 * tc) * (1 - (0.01 * rh)), 3)
                - Math.pow((15.9  + 0.117 * tc) * (1 - (0.01 * rh)), 4);
```

This also show that the subexpression `(1 - (0.01 * rh))` could be precalculated, like [answer by Eric Duminil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031624/5221149) did it.

Comment: Actually, the site does show 14 rather than 4. I will double check that as soon as I can.

Comment: I really like the alignment, it makes it much easier to parse the formula.

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and did it the way both of you suggested, simplified and changed the second multiplier. As I said in a comment below, this almost but not quite works. It has to be bad math somewhere else. I'm inputting in degrees fahrenheit (required for the homework) then converting to celsius, doing the dew point formula, and converting that answer back to fahrenheit. The simple version I was first using still give me the closest to correct answer though.